# Chef - unable to solve dependencies in alotted time

Tags: chef-infra

When I run chef-client the execution sometimes fail with this error and "Preconditions failed" message.

The first time it came I deleted the older versions of cookbooks I had in the server and it fixed this. However I still get this, intermittently.

What is the exact cause that produces this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the server has a fixed number of depsolver workers, and each of those has a timeout on a single solver attempt. You probably want to increase the number of workers in your [chef-server.rb config](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html#opscode-erchef).

The property you are looking for is `opscode_erchef['depsolver_worker_count']`. The default value is 5. To increase it:

1. SSH into the Chef Server
2. Open the (possibly empty) file at `/etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb`
3. Add the line `opscode_erchef['depsolver_worker_count'] = x` (where x is the value you want to use. Should be greater than 5). Save and close the file.
4. Run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure`

After setting the value sufficiently high (e.g. to 30), you may still find that this issue persists. In that event, repeat steps 1 and 2 above, and add the line `opscode_erchef['depsolver_timeout'] = x` (where x is the amount of time, in milliseconds, before timing out. Default is 5000. I, personally, use 30000). Then repeat step 4 as well.

Comment: Sorry for being late to accept this answer. I only tried this today. Thanks coderanger.

Comment: Even on SO you are a boss! Thanks man (This is datamancer from the IRC btw)!